# fpdf "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 88: ordinal not in range(256)"

Tags: python, pyfpdf

I am trying to convert text file into pdf in Python but I am getting error. Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

**Here my code:**

```
import fpdf
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
f = open("textfile.txt", "r")
for i in f:
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=i, ln = 1, align = 'C')
pdf.output("Output.pdf")
```

**Output: Error**

```
    p = self.pages[n].encode("latin1") if PY3K else self.pages[n] 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 88: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: You're trying to encode a unicode character into latin-1 - that can't be done. You'll have to replace it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the standard fonts in fpdf use `latin-1` encoding. If you want to write characters that aren't in the `latin-1` set, you'll need to use `set_font` to specify an external font.

Reference:
https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_font/index.html

Otherwise you'll have to convert your string to `latin-1` (using the `encode` method) and specify whether to ignore or replace the bad characters (i.e. the ones that don't exist in `latin-1`).

Comment: my text file have this type of content.

[{'id': 0, 'title': 'VOF-Verfahren – Ingenieurdienstleistungen für Technische Ausrüstung ELT (Anlagengruppe 4, 5, 6) gem § 53 HOAI, in Verbindung mit § 55 HOAI Leistungsphase 1-9 für den Neubau der Realschule Freising mit 2-fach Schulsporthalle.'}, {'id': 27, 'title': 'VOF-Verfahren – Ingenieurdienstleistungen für Technische Ausrüstung ELT (Anlagengruppe 4, 5, 6) gem § 53 HOAI, in Verbindung mit § 55 HOAI Leistungsphase 1-9 für den Neubau der Realschule Freising mit 2-fach Schulsporthalle.'}]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your code as below since it worked for me very NICE:

```
for i in f:
    pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=i.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'), ln = 1, align = 'C')
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because the default fonts for pyfpdf are latin-1 encoded.

You will need to download a utf-8 encoded font like Arial (https://www.freefontspro.com/14454/arial.ttf), place it in the same directory as the python file, and add the font using

```
fpdf.add_font("Arial", "", "arial.ttf", uni=True)
```

when you set the font use 'Arial'